# How can I add a constraint to an already existing table in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I have already created a database called contact_info in mySQL and I am trying to add a constraint to the fields firstname and lastname saying that they cannot be NULL. This is the line I am attempting to use at the moment:

```sql
ALTER TABLE contact_info MODIFY firstname, lastname DATATYPE NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not alter two columns at once. Use separate commands:

```
ALTER TABLE contact_info MODIFY firstname DATATYPE NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE contact_info MODIFY lastname DATATYPE NOT NULL;
```

Or combine them into one command with two specifications:

```
ALTER TABLE contact_info
    MODIFY firstname DATATYPE NOT NULL,
    MODIFY lastname DATATYPE NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I still get a syntax error when I try to modify each one individually. It says ERROR 1064(42000) at DATATYPE NOT NULL

Comment: I solved the problem. I misread the general syntax and was actually typing in datatype instead of varchar(15). The working line is:
ALTER TABLE contact_info MODIFY firstname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL;

Comment: Yeah "DATATYPE" is s placeholder for a real data type, like "text" or whatever

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE mytbl ADD not null (columnName);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

ALTER IGNORE TABLE table_name ADD not null (columnName);